# Can someone help me make my rectangle responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Trying to follow Treehouse but adding some of my own changes / trying new things.

```css
.rectangle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f02441;
}
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section>
        <ul id="gallery">
          <li>
            <a>
              <div class="rectangle"></div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            </a>
          </li>
```

If I make the height of the rectangle any value in px, then the rectangle appears. If I try to make it 100% or anything for that matter, it just disappears.

Here's the whole thing.
http://codepen.io/defy/pen/QwypNZ

Comment: A rectangle can't be responsive, a site can.

Comment: That codepen looks fine to me.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes isn't that just a semantic detail? It's obvious what the OP means.

Comment: Well I kind of want the rectangle to have the same dimensions as all the other images I have used. And I want it so that the rectangle gets smaller much like the images I have used do.

Comment: Of course it's semantic nitpicking, that's why I put it in a comment and not an answer. It's ontopic though in my opinion - I've seen the buzzword 'responsive' applied to a ton of ridiculous things, but this is the first time I've seen someone mention a 'responsive rectangle'.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I'd argue a rectangle can "react quickly" and therefore can be responsive

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes: Not to mention the word choice itself. When I think of "responsive design" I think of performance first, *not* about "responding" to different media types/sizes/whatnot first. It makes the idea of a "responsive rectangle" even more absurd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the height is not being set (in the CodePen demo) when you're using a percentage height is because its parent (the `a` element) doesn't currently have a set height. If you set a height by giving it `display:block;` and a working `height` value it will work.

```css
/* You should use a more specific selector, maybe a class. This is only for example */
a { 
    display:block; /* Necessary so that the height can be set */
    height:100px;  /* Set the height of the parent anchor */
}

.rectangle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f02441;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <section>
        <ul id="gallery">
          <li>
            <a>
              <div class="rectangle"></div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            </a>
          </li>
```

---

If you're wanting to set the rectangle's height to be based on the viewport's height (like the width is), you either have to either use the `vh` (viewport height) - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/nqx5hs61/)

OR

make the parent's height be based on the viewport height. If you're not using `vh`, that means that you'd have `html, body { height:100%; }` and size all other parents after `body` but before the element itself with relative heights as well - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/nqx5hs61/1/)

Comment: Can you expand on this? I don't quite understand this. I'm quite new to this by the way.

Comment: @hhaammzzaa2 I tried to make it more clear by providing a couple demos and a code snippet. If you're not understanding a certain part of it please comment with a question regarding that part :)

Comment: if i set the height of a to 100px, won't that apply to every anchor in my html? maybe i should do #gallery a

Comment: Yes, you'd use a more specific selector like that one :) the `a` in my answer is for example